# Haskell Regular expression

Tags: regex, haskell

My text file contains lines such as this:

```
[aex-ESE14 -14] this is a line
```

I have:

```
:mod +Text.Regex.Posix
```

How can i filter only lines with the above pattern and extract the contents into two strings:

```
(String, String) = ("aex-ESE14 -14","this is a line")
```

Comment: Do you _really_ want a regular expression?

Comment: sorry i can simply use split... it's been a while since i last touched haskell or programming in general

Comment: @birdlife The easiest way would probably be something like [this](https://gist.github.com/8f41934e1fadfe7d28d7) use Parsec, which I find to be easier to read and use than regex anyway.

Comment: How can anyone possibly answer this without knowing what other strings like `[aex-ESE14 -14]` you want to consider as a header? Anything in square brackets at the start of a line? A pattern of `xxx-xxxxx -xx`? This is better posed as two different questions: one about regexes (which should give a description of the problem, or at least more than one example input!), and one about how to use a given regex in haskell.

Comment: Roman Cheplyaka recently introduced me to his `regex-applicative` package, which lets you do things like this in a rather pretty way. The parser should look something like `(,) <$> (sym '[' *> many anySym <* sym ']' <* some (psym isSpace)) <*> (many anySym <* '\n')`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible way:

```
Prelude> :mod +Text.Regex.Posix
Prelude Text.Regex.Posix> let res = "[aex-ESE14 -14] this is a line" =~ "(\\[[^][]+])[[:blank:]]+(.+)" :: [[String]]
Prelude Text.Regex.Posix> res
[["[aex-ESE14 -14] this is a line","[aex-ESE14 -14]","this is a line"]]
Prelude Text.Regex.Posix> res!!0!!1
"[aex-ESE14 -14]"
Prelude Text.Regex.Posix> res!!0!!2
"this is a line"
```

The point is to match and *capture* the parts of the pattern you need to return, the rest can be just matched. To ensure `[...]` is at the start of the string, you may put a `^` at the start of the pattern.

**Pattern details**

- `(\\[[^][]+])`  - Group 1: `[` followed with 1 or more chars other than `[` and `]` and then a `]`
- `[[:blank:]]+` - 1 or more horizontal whitespace chars
- `(.+)` - 1 or more chars.

If there can be 0 or more occurrences of some pattern, replace the corresponding `+` with `*` quantifier.